# Adding .txt files to static web page only html and java script

Tags: javascript, html

It is the first time i try to create a web page and i need some help figuring out, if what I am trying to do is possible.

I have made a web page, where it is possible to upload a text file but i can not figure out how to have a text file in the source of the web page. Like withe java scripts I need the script tag in the html, is there a tag for adding other file types like .txt?

Source files in IDE

[image]

Source files inspecting web page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed the text file to show the content within the HTML page using

```
<embed src="file.txt" >
```

Answer (score 2):

You can embedd a .txt file in html using the `<iframe>` tag.

For example:

```
<iframe src="./tekst/test.txt" frameborder="0" height="400"
  width="95%"></iframe>
```